# Unable to specify parameters to parameterized source data set in ADF data flow

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a data flow that has a parameter: `TableName`.  The dataset that is used as a source within the flow is parameterized for a `TableName` parameter (SQL Server dataset).  When selecting this dataset in source setting within the ADF dataflow, it does not allow me to set the `TableName` parameter as it does when setting the source within a standard CopyActivity.

So how does one use a parameterized dataset in a dataflow if it never allows you to set the parameters?

UPDATE: The settings are actually on the DataFlow activity itself.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I understand, you mean that you can set the `TableName` in Copy Active and can't in Data Flow.

In Copy Active, we could set parameter like this:
[image]

But in Data Flow, the UI looks like:
[image]

I have a workaround is that **we could choose the table with `Query` in `Source operations`**:

```
'select * from ' +$TableName
```

[image]

Pipeline parameter:

[image]

Data Flow parameter:
[image]

It works well.

Comment: That works perfectly and I will certainly accept this answer so thank you.  However, my next task would be to figure out how I can do the same thing in the sink.  If I was able to do that, then I could have a completely generic data flow that can map from source (pass in table name) to sink (pass in table name).

Comment: @Geekn Sorry for reply you for late. We can not set it in Data Follow sink for now. May I know why you unmark it?

Answer (score 1):

In data flow, you will set the dataset parameter in Debug Settings when designing/debugging your data flow. You can then set the parameter at runtime in the data flow activity settings in the pipeline.

Comment: Actually I see it now.  You just set them in the parameters for the dataflow activity.  The work around above works, but doesn't seem necessary now..